# How can I add a stopping instruction to my fibonacci sequence?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to use recursion to make the fibonacci algorithm. I would like to print all the fibonacci to this res variable and stop when I get past this `num` parameter. I would like to know how I can do this? This code:

```
function fibs(num) {
    let i = 2;
    let res = 0;
    while (res < num) {
        res = fibs(i - 1) + fibs(i - 2);
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(fibs(10));
```

I am getting a maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Answer (score 2):

**Notes:**

⚠️ By using the first solution with small mistake like adding a big number, you can still exceed the maximum call stack size. If you think about the meaning of recursive function which is calling itself again and again, additionally it has a high calculation time.

Using the second solution you are technically using only the current stack to calculate the result. Function looks larger but not that expensive.

**Solutions:**

*First Solution - Recursive:*

This solution just works much simpler than the original one if you still want to have a solution with recursion:

```js
const fibs = (num) => {
  if (num === 1 || num === 2) {
     return 1;
  }
     
  return fibs(num - 1) + fibs(num - 2);
};

// 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
 console.log(`fibs(${i}):`, fibs(i)); 
}
```

*Second Solution - Non-Recursive:*

There is always a better solution, if I would bet I would go rather for non recursive solution, please find an example below:

```js
const fibs = (num) => {
  if (num === 1 || num === 2) {
     return 1;
  }

  let result = 1;
  let resultPrevious = 1;
  
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    const temp = result;
    result += resultPrevious;
    resultPrevious = temp;
  }
  
  return result;
};

// 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
 console.log(`fibs(${i}):`, fibs(i)); 
}
```

I was interested how the non recursive solution is faster in case of running for `fibs(30)`, please find the result below:

[image]

From the result, it seems the recursive solution was 98.86% slower at testing time for value `30`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: A suggestion: If you present the results of a jsperf.com or jsbench.me run, include a link to it here.  Here's one that includes a better recursive version: https://jsbench.me/ogk3eeplxm/1.  Note two other things: (1) The question seemed to be asking for the Fibonacci numbers up to `n`, not the first `n` Fibonacci numbers. (2) Your recursive and non-recursive functions are calculating very different things; it's not a fair comparison.

Comment: "Using the second example" - what does that mean in this context? please clarify as I see no second example in the question.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Just corrected, I meant second solution what I added there. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```js
function fibs(num) {
    let a = 0, b = 1;
    console.log(a);
    while (b < num) {
        console.log(b);
        const c = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = c;
    }
}

fibs(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explained why your code has an issue.

Here is a simple way to write a recursive function that captures the Fibonacci numbers up to `num`:

```js
const fibsTo = (num, a = 0, b = 1) => 
  a > num 
    ? []
    : [a, ... fibsTo (num, b, a + b)]

console .log (fibsTo (10))
```

This stores the current state (the most recent two values, `a` and `b`) in parameters passed through the recursive calls, starting with default values.  This returns `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]`.  If you prefer to start with `[1, 1, 2, 3, ...]`, then change the function to start with `a = 1, b = 1`.

This is not [tail-recursive](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/), and could eventually run out of stack space.  When tail-call optimization [finally becomes](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)) ubiquitous in JS, there will be reasons to use tail-recursive versions, and it doesn't hurt to do so now.  A tail-recursive version might look like this:

```js
const fibsTo = (num, fibs = [], a = 0, b = 1) => 
  a > num 
    ? fibs
    : fibsTo (num , [...fibs, a], b, a + b)
```

But there is another reason that such tail-recursion isn't so important for this problem: Long before you run out of stack space, you will run past the precision of Javascript integers.  In fact, while Fibonacci # 79 is actually 14472334024676221, JS techniques like this will produce 14472334024676220, and the error will compound from there.  This can be fixed by using [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s, but it won't matter until there is wider support for proper tail calls.

This function has approximately the [same running speed](https://jsbench.me/ogk3eeplxm/) as the non-recursive version from [norbitrial's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59022428), so as expected, recursion is not a performance-killer on a fundamentally recursive problem.

Answer (score 0):

using recursion is not the appropriate way when expecting a lot of calls.
this will make your code working slower, and in some cases - reach the maximum call stack size and get no answer.
the right way to do it is using array, like this:

```
function fibs(num) {
    let i = 1;
    let arr = [1, 1];

    while (arr[i] < num) {
        arr.push(arr[i-1] + arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of what should you write to accomplish your task

```js
function fibs(num) {
    let res = 0;
    let a = 0, b = 1;

    while(res < num){
      res = a + b;
      a = b;
      b = res;
    }
    return res;
    
}
console.log(fibs(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its not a recursion, its an infinite loop you are dealing with.

your code increment i (i++) but it dosent check in the while loop.

you can try this out:

```
function fibs(num) {
if (num>1) {
    return (fibs(num - 1) + fibs(num - 2));
}
return num;
```

}